# Using lookahead & lookbehind while ignoring whitespace and duplicates

Tags: regex, perl

I am having some trouble with the following regex:

```
(?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:).*(?=</div>)
```

It seems to capture just fine, however I can't get it to ignore whitespace.  I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
(?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:)\S*(?=</div>)
(?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:)[^\s]*(?=</div>)
```

In addition, I don't want duplicates to be captured.  I should mention that I am doing a multi/global search in perl (/g)

For the following text:

```
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>Label</strong>:  Superman</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  999.24.135.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
```

The desired result would be:

```
333.24.333.50
999.24.135.50
```

If there is a simpler/better way of going about this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(?=</div>)` But you really should use a proper XML parser

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this can be shortened or an easier way, but here is my attempt.

Using [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3A%3ADOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

my @results;
for my $div ($dom->find('div[class=Source]')
                 ->grep(sub{$_->all_text =~ /IP Address/})
                 ->each) {
    push @results, (split /:\s*/, $div->text)[1]
}

my @ips = sort(uniq(@results));
print "$_\n" for @ips;

__DATA__
<html>
<head><title>foo</title></head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>Label</strong>:  Superman</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  999.24.135.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
333.24.333.50
999.24.135.50
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this using just regex.  Do you think it is possible to do?  Borodin's answer seems to be the best way to capture without spaces, however I am not sure if this can dedup: (?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:)\s*([\d.]+)\s*(?=</div>)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
my %dup;
while(<DATA>)
{
    ($ip) = $_ =~/(?<=class="Source"><strong>IP Address<\/strong>:)\s*(.+?)(?=\<\/div\>)/g;
    $dup{$ip} = $ip;
}

my @ip_ad = keys %dup;
print @ip_ad;


__DATA__
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>Label</strong>:  Superman</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  999.24.135.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
<div style="margin-left: 12em;" class="Source"><strong>IP Address</strong>:  333.24.333.50</div>
```